# Why I can't open localhost with nginx and docker?

Tags: docker, nginx

1. I have OSX and Docker.

   2. docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'
  services:
    web:
      image: nginx:stable
      ports:
        - "8010:80"
```

3. Run docker-compose up -d
4. Open http://localhost:8010/

And I got **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

Why it does not work for me and I didn't get **"Welcome To Nginx"**

Comment: Very little information to help. Please check if the container is running using `docker ps`. If the container is not running, check the logs using `docker logs <container-id>`. Then go inside the container and check if `curl localhost` works. Docker compose file looks alright.

Comment: @PalashGoel container is running. Ports 0.0.0.0:8010->80/tcp
Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

Comment: Check the docker logs then.

Comment: @PalashGoel changed docker-compose file port to 8080 and now it works.

Comment: Was port 8010 already occupied?

Comment: I tried 8010, 9898, etc, not working, only 8080 - ok.